# Django: Integrity error not null for ForeignKey id field

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have a model which contains ForeignKeys to a number of other models and find, for some reason, I am able to save one of these models absolutely fine, but another I receive a fault message saying:
`IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: app_eofsr.flight_id`
See below for my models.py:

```
# models.py
class Aircraft(models.Model):
    esn = models.IntegerField()
    acid = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    engpos = models.IntegerField()
    operator = models.CharField(max_length=5, default='---')
    fleet = models.ForeignKey(Fleet, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(default=None, editable=False, max_length=50, unique=True)

class EoFSR(models.Model):
    datetime_eofsr = models.DateTimeField(default=None)
    flight_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    city_from = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    city_to = models.CharField(max_length=4)
```

and these both feed into this model:

```
# models.py
class Flight(models.Model):
    flight_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    city_from = models.CharField(max_length=4, default=None)
    city_to = models.CharField(max_length=4, default=None)
    datetime_start = models.DateTimeField(default=None)
    aircraft = models.ForeignKey(Aircraft, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    eofsr = models.ForeignKey(EoFSR, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The odd thing being, I can save an Aircraft record no problem at all, but cannot save an EoFSR record and receive the NOT NULL constraint error message.  I've done the usual deleting of the migrations and even tried deleting the db.sqlite3, but still no luck!  Any suggestions?

Comment: IntegrityError means it is something wrong with db integration. Have You tried to migrate app into db using: `python3 manage.py migrate app_name`?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, I was able to do makemigrations and migrate with no issues at all.  I tried this again after deleting the files in the migrations folder and still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try to set null=True in models You have ForeignKey() like:

```
aircraft = models.ForeignKey(Aircraft, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

, then makemigrations and migrate